# Posting Picture on Event Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall, facebook-events

i am having a Problem posting a Picture in the Wall of an Event on Facebook.
It is Posting

My current Code is:

```
$post_array = array(
    "access_token" => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
    'source' => "@" . realpath("image.png"),
    'message' => 'Some Message'
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/".$event_id['id']."/feed", "POST", $post_array);
```

Everything is working fine, except for the Image: It won't be displayed.

Any Help out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for Events, Try:

```
//Setup the Facebook object for file upload
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'your_app_id_here',
  'secret' => 'your_secret_here',
  'cookie' => true,
  'fileUpload' => true
));
```

Then:

```
$file = "image.png";
//The event information array (timestamps are "Facebook time"...)
$event_info = array(
    "access_token' => 'your access token",    
    "name" => "Event Title",    
    "start_time" => 1290790800,
    "end_time" => 1290799800,
    "location" => "Your Location",
    "description" => "Event Description"
);

$event_info[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);

$result = $facebook->api('me/events','post',$event_info);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping. But i am searching a possibility to POst a Picture to the Wall of the Event, not as Picture in the Event (That's working fine)